# Table subtitle in Stata estout to LaTex-table

Tags: tables, stata

I am trying to write table "subtitle" text that sits on top of the table, below the caption. I am using esttab in Stata to get the output below, but I am unable to make the aforementioned changes.

Further, I am trying to change the font size of the table caption. Can anyone help me with this?

```
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{adjustbox}{max
width={\textwidth},caption={Descriptive statistics, exchange type. Purchase only},nofloat=table}
\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{ccccc}}
\hline\hline
\hline\hline
\end{tabular}\end{adjustbox}
```

Comment: This depends quite a lot on the how long the "subtitle" text is and how you would like to align it with respect to the caption and the table. Therefore, a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) as well as a sketch of the desired output would be really helpful here. Regarding the caption's font size: Take a look at the `caption` package. Since you used `adjustbox` on the tabular, please be aware, that this will lead to inconsistent font sized throughout your document. There are better methods than `adjustbox`, which one to use depends on the table's contents.